# Trying to render different view between mobile and web from Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cross-browser

I'm trying to render different views for each type of device. If is true, mobile will be rendered,  **mobile.ejs** file, if isn't mobile, **'pages/index.js'**.

Currently, my file **index.js** is responsible for configuration from Express.

Express:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const req = require('request')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const browser = require('browser-detect') 
const router = express.Router()

if(browser) {
  router.get('/', req => {
    const result = browser(req.headers['user-agent']);

    resultadoMobile = (result.mobile)

      if (resultadoMobile) {
        resultPath = "pages/mobile";
        return resultPath;
      }
      else {
        resultPath = "pages/index";
        return resultPath;
      }
  })

}

express() 

  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .use (bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render(resultPath))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Servidor iniciado em  ${ PORT }`))
```

So, to summarize:

I need to use *browser-detect* to detect if is mobile, if is true, render **'pages /mobile.ejs'**, if not **'pages/index.ejs'**.

The answer from the server is:

```
ReferenceError: **resultPath** is not defined
    at express.use.set.set.use.get (\path\**\\index.js:33:38)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (\path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (\path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at \path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (\path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (\path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (\path\**\\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\path\**\\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: What's resultPath and why do you expect it to be defined?

Comment: In this case, "result.mobile" return if mobile is true or not. Then, resultadoMobile receive the value of this question. So, if resultadoMobile is true, its print "pages/mobile.ejs" when somone request "/" in url. 

I expect to print "pages/index.ejs" or "pages/mobile.ejs". depends of the case.

Comment: The code seems to be overly complicated and doesn't show the intention clearly. If it's that simple then it can be simpler, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resultPath` variable doesn't exist and there may be no need for one.

It likely should be:

```
.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const isMobile = browser(req.headers['user-agent']).mobile;
  res.render(isMobile ? "pages/mobile" : "pages/index");
});
```